# Joomla - Modifying default category list view (through overrides?)

Tags: overrides, category

I'm building a site for a friend and I should state that this is not what I'm doing for living. I just started working with Joomla a few days ago.

Everything is good so far, except I'm stuck at one point.

This is a site for a construction company and I need to create articles for on-going and completed projects. I will create an article for each project and each article will belong to a category, 'Completed' and 'On-Going', respectfully.

I plan to create menu links for 'Completed' and 'On-Going' categories in main menu. I also want to present a thumbnail of the article on the category list. Problem is, standard look of the category list is kinda ugly, and I have no idea how to change it. I'm using a template named PixelDot, but it does not seem to do any good for my problem.

During my research, I stumbled upon concepts 'Layout Overrides' and 'Alternative Layouts'. I have basic html and css knowledge, also some PHP, but I am totally lost on which file(s) to modify. I also need a little help on get the entry text picture as a thumbnail on the category list (this is the list where you see 'articles' aka projects which belongs to the category (completed or on-going), when you clicked on relevant menu button)

Any help will be highly appreciated. My Joomla version is 3.4.1. (which I believe most up-to-date version as today)

I'm sometimes making it more complex while I try to make things detailed and clear, I hope this is not one of those cases.

Comment: You can split this. You'll get better results if you ask about the intro text and thumbnail in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want to accomplish is better done through a layout override. The good news is that it is pretty simple since you only have to copy working code to a folder inside your template and modify it from there.

Take a look at this https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides.

There's a cheatsheet near the end telling you exactly what to copy and where.