# Display list of files under categories on K2 in visually-appealing ways

Tags: k2, layout

Using K2 component. Did not like default look of files listed under categories (http://www.wilddusk.com/wild-india) with images of directories. How one can explore other visually-appealing way?

Comment: Try layout overrides. I answered a similar question here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10033/joomla-modifying-default-category-list-view-through-overrides/10040#10040

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple, actually.

Find a beautiful template on the web, then upload it to your site, then modify the category, or categories, that you're listing, to use that template in the backend:

> Administrator Menu: "K2" -> "Categories" -> "Edit Category" -> "Category Item
>   Layout" (Tab on the right) -> "Select a template"

Or you can create your own template, and there is a resource to help you with that: http://y-designs.com/ja/blog-ja/k2-templating-from-0-to-100mph-in/